# Проблема с получением ссылки на файл в SD карте

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, мне показали интересную библиотеку [afileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)

Ловит все(даже с помощью ES проводника) однако с карты памяти не хочет.
 ***Если нажать item Видео или галерея и выбрать видео или картинку с карты памяти то ссылку возвращает*** однако напрямую возвращать не хочет. В чем может заключаться неисправнось? И как подправить? [image: Выбрал файл с карты памяти]
[image: результат]
[image: интерфейс программы]

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 Paul Burke
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.ipaulpro.afilechooserexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils;

/**
 * @author paulburke (ipaulpro)
 */
public class FileChooserExampleActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "FileChooserExampleActivity";

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 6384; // onActivityResult request
                                                  // code

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a simple button to start the file chooser process
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(R.string.choose_file);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Display the file chooser dialog
                showChooser();
            }
        });

        setContentView(button);
    }

    private void showChooser() {
        // Use the GET_CONTENT intent from the utility class
        Intent target = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();
        // Create the chooser Intent
        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(
                target, getString(R.string.chooser_title));
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            // The reason for the existence of aFileChooser
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                // If the file selection was successful
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        // Get the URI of the selected file
                        final Uri uri = data.getData();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Uri = " + uri.toString());
                        try {
                            // Get the file path from the URI
                            final String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
                            Toast.makeText(FileChooserExampleActivity.this,
                                    "File Selected: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("FileSelectorTestActivity", "File select error", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите____код

Comment: Это пример от автора и не работает карта памяти ( флешка кстати тоже)

Comment: А что содержится в переменной uri? Она тоже null?

Comment: Переменная не null так как data не null, в ней содержится Uri data. + К всему этому с встроенной памятью работает хорошо

Comment: `однако напрямую возвращать не хочет` – что значит напрямую?

Comment: Это значит через item MicroSD или ES проводник. Когда я сам выбираю где файл лежит. Оно не возвращает ссылку на сам файл

Answer (score 0):

Это не неисправность а фича :)

Начиная с KitKat доступ к карте памяти для приложений подписанных простыми смертными ограничен. Нужно иметь подпись вендора аппарата или самого Google :)

Мильон тыщу раз об этом [уже писалось](https://www.androidcentral.com/kitkat-sdcard-changes)

Обсуждение этой проблемы применительно к aFileChooser - [здесь](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/issues/58)

Если говорить по сути, то доступа к произвольным файлам на внешней карте памяти нет между KitKat и LolliPop - и дело тут не в aFileChooser, а в принципе.

**Update**

Для версии Android >= 6.0 проблему можно решить предоставлением [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) на доступ к карте памяти.

Comment: Проверил программу на 4.2.2 она выглядит совсем по другому ( если использовать ES проводник для выбора файла, например субтитров )то ссылку возвращает, а если видео то нет. Тут дело в том что оно не все возвращает даже на 4.2.2

Comment: Я внёс коррективу с гитхаба (но эта корректива не работает на lilipop) там об этом писалось,+ я проверил

Comment: И не будет работать... Работать будет только с N

Comment: Я что посоветуете? Я новичек в этом..

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: Мне нужно это нет не только >= 6.0  а и для lilipop & 4.4, та и для 4.2.2

Comment: Может я сам что то смогу сделать? Просто направьте, от чего отталкиваться, сам ещё до конца не понимаю андроид, как раз будет хорошая практика

Comment: В том же es проводник для работы с карты памяти неуклонно читать директорию или как то так, но я не пойму что значит выбрать

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/254813/ вроде нашел ответ

Comment: Вы немного запутали меня - вам нужно писать на карту памяти или получить путь к карте памяти?

Comment: Получить путь, а потом обработать содержимое. Например, получаю файл субтитров и уже что то делаю с этой стрингой

Comment: Пока не разберусь сам, будет только с встроенной работать (Бетта версия)